# calculating duration between two datetime stamps - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, calculation

is it possible to get an exact duration between timestamps?
for example;

```
Start time = 2022-02-24 11:27:00
End time = 2022-04-26 12:00:00
Duration = 48hrs 33mins
```

Originally I was using the date diff but that only brings back the hours but the requirements have since changed.
Also tried using date name & date part functions..

any suggestions??

Comment: Maybe like [this sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/cmEnE9-J) which you can simplify off course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use the Dateadd DateDiff pattern

```
DECLARE @then DATETIME ='2022-02-24 11:27:00'
DECLARE @now DATETIME ='2022-02-26 12:00:00'
DECLARE @diff DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@then,@now),0)
    
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(hh,0,@diff) as VARCHAR(10))+'hrs '+
CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,@diff)AS VARCHAR(2)) +'mins'
```

Comment: have you tried that with `DECLARE @then DATETIME = '2022-02-24 11:27:00'` and 
`DECLARE @now DATETIME = '2022-04-26 12:00:00'` ? It resuls in an overflow

Comment: you were right, I'd focused on the time being in the same day, code amended.